# UWP TextBox.Text binding not updating when using PlaceholderText

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, uwp

I've got some text boxes for which i wanted to set the `PlaceholderText` property. The text of each box is bound to a property of the underlying view model. Now when setting the placeholder in the XAML like that

```
<TextBox PlaceholderText="Placeholder" Text={Binding PropertyName} />
```

i noticed, that the view model's properties are not updated anymore when the text box loses focus.
Whereas without placeholder the binding works just fine.

Is this behaviour intended and if are there any workarounds, or do i have to stick to a classic `TextBlock` that describes the intended input each box?

**Edit:** The property does implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the binding is updated in the view model when no placeholder is set.

Comment: Try setting UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged. And just a note: you don't even have to use a TextBlock. Just set the Header property.

Comment: @RareNCool Unfortunately setting the `UpdateSourceTrigger` doesn't change anything. But thanks for the tip with the `Header` property.

Comment: does the property the textblock is bound too implement INotiftyProperty changed interface?

Comment: Try Text="{x:Bind PropertyName, Mode=TwoWay}"

Comment: @KenTucker Yes, the property does implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and it does work when not setting a placeholder text.

Comment: @Jackie I've never used x:Bind before, but it seems i would need to have the property inside the view instead of the view model, so this would be only an option if anything works.

Comment: Did you property set the DataContext of the view to the viewmodel? Looks like you did because otherwise without the PlaceholderText setting, it wouldn't work either.

Comment: @Jackie I have to excuse, using {x:Bind viewModel.Property, Mode=TwoWay} does compile, but as before the view model is not updated by the binding.

Comment: Could you try setting the DataContext of the view to your ViewModel? I have tried it here and the binding works with or without the PlaceHolderText setting.

Comment: @Jackie Nevermind... It started working after cleaning the solution using {Binding Property, Mode=TwoWay}. Should've taken a closer look at the docs... OneWay is the default binding mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PlaceholderText for TextBox does not change the TextBox behavior when it loses focus.

You can try explicitly using the "TwoWay" binding mode for the Text property, instead of the "Default" binding mode.

```
<TextBox PlaceholderText="Placeholder" Text="{x:Bind PropertyName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Make sure your View's DataContext is set to your viewmodel, something like below

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();

        this.InitializeComponent();            
    }
```

For more information on Binding mode, see to

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt204783.aspx

Comment: So what we are saying here is that the default binding mode for the standard text input control is OneWay... I understand common patterns for using textboxes with OneWay binding, but surely the default for an input control should be two way.

Comment: That's what I thought, coming from my experience in WPF. But in UWP, the default is one way.